# Nodejs Http request has no response

Tags: node.js, http, get, response

Currently using http GET to an external API. When called individually, the response is good. When put in a for loop, some requests don't seem to have a response.

This is the http GET function:

```
function httpGetChunk(url, callback) {
    http.get(url, function(resp) {
        var body='';
        resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk; //chunk too large from this response
        });
        resp.on('end', function() {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            callback(data);
        });
        resp.on("error", function(e) {
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
        });
    });
}
```

When I call the GET function in a for loop for 5 different urls, I only get responses for some of them. Ran it a couple of times and the response would be from a different combination of the called urls but never all of them.

Any insight?

**Edit 1:** To give more information, my for loop looks something like this.

```
for (var i=0;i<5; i++) {
    httpGetChunk(someUrl, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

This would only print out some responses but not all.

**Edit 2:** 
I've taken into account all the advice on this thread. I'm now using the async module and have increased the number of concurrent connections to 20:

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 20;
```

Following code is the one im currently testing:

getMatchStats() returns an game 'match' object with statistics (e.g kills, deaths in the match etc.)

matchIds is the array containing all the id keys of the matches

```
async.parallel([
    getMatchStats(matchIds[0], function (matchData) {
        console.log('0');
    }),
    getMatchStats(matchIds[1], function (matchData) {
        console.log('1');
    }),
    getMatchStats(matchIds[2], function (matchData) {
        console.log('2');
    }),
    getMatchStats(matchIds[3], function (matchData) {
        console.log('3');
    }),
    getMatchStats(matchIds[4], function (matchData) {
        console.log('4');
    }),
], function(err, result) {
    console.log('done');
    callback(result);
});
```

and getMatchStats

```
function getMatchStats(matchId, callback) {
    var url = getMatchStatsUrl(matchId); //gets url based on id
    httpGetChunk(url, function(data) {
        callback(data);
    });
}
```

again, the async.parallel never finishes since only some of the requests have responses. Every time i run it, the responses would be from a different combination of matches. Sometimes, it even completes all of the requests.

Maybe my OS has limitations on number of connections (im testing on localhost)?

Comment: Node itself has a fairly small limit on the number of simultaneous socket connections it will allow.  It's possible you're running out of sockets by trying to do multiple requests in parallel.  The node socket limit can be increased and I think the default has already been raised in the newest node.js version.  I have no idea if that is your specific issue or not, but it could be).

Comment: Use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). It makes your life so much easier.

Comment: @jfriend00 I looked into it and im currently using 0.10 nodejs which has a limitation on socket connections. I've increased the limit and problem still exists.

Comment: Then, I would wonder if the server you are calling has concurrency issues (when more than one request arrives at the same time).  I'd suggest you look at a network sniffer (like WireShark) and see exactly what is being sent and received over the wire to perhaps illuminate what is going on.  You need to figure out whether this is a problem with your local code or a problem with the server you are making a request from.

Answer (score 1):

Each request is asynchronous. So, if you use a regular `for` loop, each step is going to be executed synchronously and won't wait for callback to be called. What do you need is something like the [`each`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#each) method from the [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module, like:

```
async.each(yourArrayOfUrls, function (url, callback) {
  httpGetChunk(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    callback();
  });
}, function (err) {
  // if some step produce an error, you can get it here...
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the for loop just spawn a bunch of asynchronous http requests? the callbacks should still be called right? also, I tried the async and problem still exists

Comment: Yes, your `for` loop spawns a bunch of asynchronous requests, but in a synchronous way, so when the loop ends, not all the requests have returned. That's why you should never use sync loops to run async calls. In those cases, you should use something like the `async` module, or even promises. In your scenario, the only reason for you haven't seen the logs for all your requests is that one of them returned an error, and you can catch it in the last function of `async.each` method.